# Backup Kubernetes Node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I use 1 master 2 workers Kubernetes Cluster.
master and 1. worker: at location a
2. worker: at location b.

Location a and b is very far from each other.

I want to run the pods at location a, but if a down it is created at location b.

I want to create a pod in the worst scenario at location b.

How can I do this in Kubernetes?

Comment: What you're looking for is node affinity: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity

Comment: @Levent Have the above suggestion solved your problem?

Comment: Hey @Levent, I would suggest you to correct the subject of your question, it does not reflect well the real nature of your problem, and sounds ambiguous.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Stack Overflow's best practices for asking a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer.

As @Burak mentioned in his comment:

What you're looking for is [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity):

> – it allows you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be
>   scheduled on, based on labels on the node.
>
> Node affinity is specified as field nodeAffinity of field affinity in
>   the PodSpec.
>
> Here’s an example of a pod that uses node affinity:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 1
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: another-node-label-key
            operator: In
            values:
            - another-node-label-value
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

You can find all the necessary details in the linked documentation.

Please let me know if that helped.